# Sorting antd column having multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, tablesorter

I have a column in my **antd table** called Specialities. The data(`**specialities**`) in that column is coming from back end as an array collection.

[image]

[image]

What I tried to do is

```
{
    title: 'Specialties',
    dataIndex: 'specialties',
    key: 'specialties',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.specialties.localeCompare(b.specialties),
    render: (val, record)=><div title={val} className="text_overlap">{val.map((a)=>a.name).toString()}</div>
}
```

I get this error while doing this

> TypeError: a.specialties.localeCompare is not a function

How can I **sort** this column where data is coming from an **array collection**?

Comment: Do you want to sort the `specialties` array based on the `name`?

Comment: want to sort according to name in each column in the table

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort according to each column name you need to concat the names in any row.

```
sorter: (a, b) => {
  return a
    .specialities
    .map((g) => g.name)
    .join("")
    .localeCompare(b.specialities.map((h) => h.name).join(""));
},
```

Live example:

[image: Edit wizardly-shadow-7nv54]

Comment: This solution worked for me! author @Jane pls mark this as one the of accepted answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use localCompare, but on the field name in the object

```js
const data = {
  foo: "bar",
  specialities: [
    {name: 'Medical'},
    {name: 'Cooking'},
    {name: 'Telemetry'}
  ]
}
data.specialities.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
console.log(data)
```

In your object, you specify the `key`, so just need to specify the field

```
{
    title: 'Specialties',
    dataIndex: 'specialties',
    key: 'specialties',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name),
    render: (val, record)=><div title={val} className="text_overlap">{val.map((a)=>a.name).toString()}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) only works on string type.

You need to compare on `name` field of the `localeCompare`

```
sorter: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
```

If you want to add sort methods for all the columns, you can set `sortDirections: ['ascend' | 'descend']` on table props.